# GSON is deprecated. Which one we can use to serialize and deserialize Java objects to and from JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences, gson

Hi I want to store the Java Objects.

I have searched and found that the GSON library is doing the conversion of Java Object to Json String and vice versa. Then I can store the converted JSON String into the Shared Preferences.

But That GSON library is deprecated and there is no update after May 2013.

Kindly provide me an alternate way to implement the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this as off-topic as requesting an off-the-site library, but then it's reasonably specific about "proper" way to replace a deprecated, more-or-less standard, library.

Comment: Gson is not deprecated. It was last updated November, 20th 2014. See [its official repository](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). The downloads page was not updated ([see why](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/diQlloTQuCk)), but the [Maven Repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.3.1%7Cjar) was. The last version is 2.3.1.

Comment: @Aleks Yes as you said I am looking for an proper library. @ Egor Where can I get the latest jar file or else I have to use the old one which was deprecated. Thanks.

Comment: @MVignesh you can download it from the [Maven Repository](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GSON is not deprecated and seems to be well supported ([commit history](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/list)). If you are looking for an alternative [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) is a popular one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason for that is that google suggests to switch to Android Studio and if you do so there's no need for downloading jar, you simple put **compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'**   in dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

From [Gson README.md](https://github.com/google/gson#gson)

```
ℹ️ Gson is currently in maintenance mode; existing bugs will be
 fixed, but large new features will likely not be added. If you want 
to add a new feature, please first search for existing GitHub 
issues, or create a new one to discuss the feature and get feedback.
```

so I'd say it **IS** deprecated.

I agree with the other answer that [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) is a pretty popular one.